# Resource injection in Spring Boot not working with gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, intellij-13

I have a Configuration bean.

```
@Component
public class Config {

   @Value("classpath:${app.file.name.srgbicc}")
   public Resource icc;

   @PostConstruct
   void init(){
      try {
         tempdir = Files.createTempDir();
         newIcc = copyIccFileToTemp();           
      }catch (IOException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
  }

  private File copyIccFileToTemp() throws IOException {
      File tempIcc = new File(tempdir, icc.getFilename());
      FileUtils.copyFile(icc.getFile(),tempIcc);
      return tempIcc;
  }
```

}

On `icc.getFile()` there is a FileNotFoundException

application.properties

```
app.file.name.srgbicc = sRGB.icc
```

I looked in my classpath and found the following situation:

```
build/classes/main (no icc file)
build/resources/main (icc file, application.properties)
```

When printed out my classpath during application start I only found `...myApp/build/classes/main`. 
No `../build/resources/main` or `../src/main/resources` entries there.

So I was wondering why is the resources not on the classpath?
according to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-running-applications
this should be.

Of course if I put the icc file in `build/classes/main` its all working as expected, but it is not supposed to be there. right?

I tried to run the application with `gradle run` or `gradle bootRun` in intellij I use `static main`.  The good thing is that the application fails consistently independent of how I start it.

My Project layout

```
myApp
     src
        main
           java
               pkg
                  Config.java
           resources
               sRGB.icc
               application.properties
```

For the reference:
IntelliJ 13
spring-boot 1.1.5
Fgradle 2.0

Update
Here is a stripped down example of my code 
https://gist.github.com/Vad1mo/bb5d23ca251341236fbd

I removed @PostConstruct in the config.init and run the application with gradle build all test are success when i rund from intellij the tests fail. this is strange that i know have different behavior

Comment: How exactly do you run the app (Gradle or IntelliJ), and where exactly did you put the resource file? Looks like something is misconfigured, as the processed resource file should go into `build/resources/main`, not `build/classes/resources/main`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I had an copy & paste error when creating the question. My path is `build/resources/main`

Comment: How exactly do you run the app (Gradle or IntelliJ), and where exactly did you put the resource file?

Comment: @Peter I updated my question. I just run gradle run or gradle bootRun no parameters. Setup is plain vanilla spring boot tutorial. will try to setup an example project.

Comment: Your project layout has `src/resources`, however it needs to be `src/main/resources`.

Comment: the project layout is src/main/resources as indicated in text but wrong idented in diagram

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60418/discussion-between-vadimo-and-peter-niederwieser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now.

What helped me was just to do a simple `clean build` and rebuild project in intellij. I was using to much eclipse and maven so I expected it to happen automagically.